# Monotonicity of $L^p$ norms

Tags: measure-theory, lp-spaces

Let $(X, \mathscr{A})$ be a measurable space, and let $\mu$ be a measure on $(X, \mathscr{A})$ such tat $\mu(X) = 1$  suppose that $1\leq p_1 < p_2 < +\infty$.

Show that if $f$ belongs to $\mathscr{L} ^{p_2}(X,\mathscr{A}, \mu) $ then $f$ belongs to $\mathscr{L} ^{p_1}(X,\mathscr{A}, \mu) $ and satisfies $\| f\| _{p_1} \leq \| f\| _{p_2}$

Is there a typo in my exercise?
For $\ell_p$ spaces it seems to be the other way around:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space

Thankful for help

Comment: No typo. What did you try?

Comment: Exactly, it IS the other way around!

Comment: Hint: Jensen's inequality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The assumption $\mu(X)=1$ is crucial. It's not satisfied by the set of natural numbers, hence it's not surprising it doesn't work in this case.

One case use Jensen's inequality with the convex function $x\mapsto |x|^{p_2/p_1}$.